# Does rsync overwrite the new file

Tags: rsync

i use `rsync -avh`

I just want to know that if the file on destination already exists does the rsync overwrite the new file or not

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the file contents are the same, then no; it will merely fudge the metadata to match. If the file contents differ then the file will be overwritten; use `--ignore-existing` to change this behavior, or `-u` to use a different, sane behavior.

Comment: So it actually replaces the file, not update? If that file is hard-linked, the the other link is unaffected?

Comment: @Mark Asking the important question here.

Comment: It looks like you are correct that it replaces the file by default, thus "breaking" the hard link. I just noticed an --inplace option: "instead of the default method of creating a new copy of the file and moving it into place when it is complete, rsync instead writes the updated data directly to the destination file." "Hard  links  are not broken.  This means the new data will be visible through other hard links to the destination file."